# Spacing between TableRow Material-UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I would like to add space between **TableRow MaterialUI** components. How can I accomplish that?

```
<S.MainTable>
  <TableBody>
   {rows.map(row => {
     return (
       <S.StyledTableRow key={row.id}>
         <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{row.name}</TableCell>
         <TableCell numeric>{row.calories}</TableCell>
         <TableCell numeric>{row.fat}</TableCell>
         <TableCell numeric>{row.carbs}</TableCell>
         <TableCell numeric>{row.protein}</TableCell>
       </S.StyledTableRow>
           );
         })}
  </TableBody>
</S.MainTable>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add these few lines of code to your table's CSS:

```
{
     border-spacing: 0 5px !important;
     border-collapse: separate !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add spaces between the row of the table by defining paddingBottom and  paddingTop in the  just like that

```
<TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 10, paddingTop: 10 }} colSpan={2}>
           <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
               <Box margin={1}>
                   <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                       ENGAGEMENT HISTORY
           </Typography>
                   <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                       <TableHead>
                           <TableRow>
                               <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                               <TableCell>Club</TableCell>
                               <TableCell align="right">Staff</TableCell>
                           </TableRow>
                       </TableHead>
                       <TableBody>
                           {row.engagementHistory.map((historyRow) => (
                               <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                                   <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                       {historyRow.date}
                                   </TableCell>
                                   <TableCell>{historyRow.contact}</TableCell>
                                   <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.staff}</TableCell>
                               </TableRow>
                           ))}
                       </TableBody>
                   </Table>
               </Box>
           </Collapse>
       </TableCell>
```

[image]

Comment: can you add a sandbox? It does not seem to work right now!

Comment: yes i can are you still looking for the answer of that question ? if yes then i will do that for you

Comment: can you provide right answer for this .i am looking for same

Answer (score -2):

Did you used  "break" tag? or u can also do with margin and padding .

Comment: please elaborate your answer by showing an example or code.